# How to delete specific column value from db in yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to delete updated value from db. Like if the notice is inserted of **notice column** in **class table** and I want to delete it. So what will be the query in yii2? Please help -

```html
$model = Class::find()->where('id', $id)->one;
$model->delete();
```

Above query is for -

```html
DELETE FROM class WHERE id = $id;
```

I want to write query like that in yii2 -

```html
DELETE notice FROM class WHERE id = $id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching using the primary key, you can use

```
$model = Class::findOne($id);
```

Then, for deleting (setting to null) the notice field, you just need to use

```
$model->notice = NULL;
$model->save();
```

Note that if the notice attribute is required, or not null, the save will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yii allows you to execute SQL command direct 
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command

```
$query = "DELETE notice FROM class WHERE id = {$id}";
Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)->execute();
```